# Loop through SQL Table valued parameter

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql, table-valued-parameters

I'm trying to achieve a advanced search functionality for my application in which i have a `SQL` Table Valued Parameter in the following structure,

```
ColumnName   Operator       Keyword
------------------------------------
Name          StartsWith     Ram
City          Equals         Chennai
```

My `SQL` table,

```
Name         City      CreatedDate
-----------------------------------
Ram          Chennai   10/10/2014
Ramachan     Kovai     02/03/2015
```

How can i loop thorough this `TVP` so that i can build the `WHERE` clause and can append it to the `SELECT` query which is faster since i have some 10 rows of search values(criteria).

The filters are associated with `AND` operator.

List of operators used:

1. Equals
2. Not equals
3. Starts with
4. Ends with
5. From(Date)
6. To(Date)

Comment: Simply build the query on the client.

Comment: how are your filters associated with each other? using `AND` or `OR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dynamic filtered expression like below and use it in your SQL. You need to be very careful when adding editing filters in your TVP and verifying it against respective datatypes as well

**Create Type and Base Table with Data**

```
/*
CREATE TYPE FilterTVP AS TABLE
(
ColumnName VARCHAR(30), Operator VARCHAR(30), Keyword VARCHAR(30)
);
GO

CREATE TABLE myTable
(
    Name VARCHAR(50),
    City VARCHAR(50),
    CreatedDate DATE
)
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES('Ram','Chennai','10/10/2014'),('Ramachan','Kovai','02/03/2015')

*/
```

**Query**

```
DECLARE @Param FilterTVP
INSERT INTO @Param VALUES('Name','StartsWith','Ram'),('City','Equals','Chennai'),('CreatedDate','From','2014-05-05')
DECLARE @FilterExp NVARCHAR(MAX) 
SELECT @FilterExp = 
(SELECT
    ' AND ' + QUOTENAME(ColumnName,'[') + ' ' + 
    CASE Operator 
        WHEN 'Equals'
        THEN '='
        WHEN 'Not equals'
        THEN '<>'
        WHEN 'StartsWith'
        THEN 'LIKE'
        WHEN 'Endswith'
        THEN 'LIKE'
        WHEN 'From'
        THEN '>='
        WHEN 'To'
        THEN '<='

    END + ' ' +
    CASE
        WHEN Operator = 'Startswith' THEN  QUOTENAME(Keyword  + '%','''') 
        WHEN Operator = 'Endswith' THEN QUOTENAME('%' + Keyword  ,'''') 
        ELSE QUOTENAME(Keyword,'''')
    END
FROM @Param
FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)')



SET @FilterExp = 'SELECT * FROM  myTable WHERE 1=1 ' + ISNULL(@FilterExp,'')

PRINT @FilterExp
EXEC sp_executeSQL @FilterExp
```

**Output**

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8c3aa/1)

```
Name    City    CreatedDate
--------------------------
Ram Chennai 2014-10-10
```

Answer (score 0):

Build your statement and then execute it like for example:

```
CREATE TABLE f
    (
      ColumnName NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
      Operator NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
      KeyWord NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )
CREATE TABLE t
    (
      Name NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
      City NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )

INSERT  INTO f
VALUES  ( 'Name', 'StartsWith', 'Ram' ),
        ( 'City', 'Equals', 'Chennai' )


INSERT  INTO t
VALUES  ( 'Ram', 'Chennai' ),
        ( 'Ramachan', 'Kovai' )


DECLARE @op NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
    @v NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @statement NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * FROM t WHERE Name ' 

SELECT  @op = Operator ,
        @v = KeyWord
FROM    f
WHERE   ColumnName = 'Name'

SET @statement = @statement + CASE @op
                                WHEN 'StartsWith' THEN 'LIKE ''' + @v + '%'''
                                ELSE ' = ''' + @v + ''''
                              END + ' AND City'


SELECT  @op = Operator ,
        @v = KeyWord
FROM    f
WHERE   ColumnName = 'City'

SET @statement = @statement + CASE @op
                                WHEN 'StartsWith' THEN 'LIKE ''%' + @v + '%'''
                                ELSE ' = ''' + @v + ''''
                              END

EXEC(@statement)
```

Output:

```
Name    City
Ram     Chennai
```